# Opening instagram app on mobile and url on desktop?

Tags: html, wordpress

I am trying to open the instagram and linked in apps on a holding page I am building and am trying to find a way for the app to open when clicked on mobile and the direct url profile to open when clicked on a laptop/desktop?

```
        <div class="icon1"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/luke-fearon-853606158/" target="_blank"></a></div>
        <div class="icon3"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/five_mile_food" target="_blank"></a></div>
```

Links are working for desktop and I know I have to use user id's for opening the app on mobile but how do i implement the code in html to open the relevant platform, also if the apps arent installed fallback to the url so the clicked link still opens something on mobile

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following methods to make a link open the Instagram app on a users device:

**1st Method**

```
<a href="http://instagram.com/_u/{USERNAME}/">Link to Instagram Page</a>
```

- Ask user to select application to launch with

**2nd Method**

```
<a href="instagram://user?username={USERNAME}">Link to Instagram Profile</a>
```

- If user installed instagram application : Directly launch page with native application
- If user not installed instagram application : Do nothing

Comment: and this works on both mobile and desktop? I dont need seperate addresses? and the user name has to be inbetween { } ?

Comment: You need a different link for desktop. You could solve the issue with showing the right link on mobile and desktop by hiding and showing the links by the use media queries in CSS. I dont think you need the {} around the username

Comment: i have used the method 1 and the instagram is opening the desktop url on my localhost will this change when clicked on mobile as im not sure if chrome developer tools recognises the mobile view as an actual mobile device? should this be happening or do i need to use the specific id like in this example for it to open in app?  <a href="instagram://user?username=barackobama">Instagram</a>

Comment: i think i get it now i basically have to assign a class to each 'a' tag and display or hide relevant to my css media queries? essentially by having 2 a tags inside the same location <div> for the link?

Comment: Yep thats exactly what you need :)

Comment: If you get it working, can you approve my answer? :)